# reading param from the current url in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Yes there are alot of questions been asked about this topic. But I couldn't get solution for my problem.

Here is my url

```
http://localhost/resetpassword.html/7f18114f-1e1b-4c73-bf0f-f9e6f5bbb293
```

And user will be able to get this screen just by clicking the link provided by email. I have tried using $routeParams, $location.search() but can't find my param.

I am using nodejs as my web server. From the server side routing I have added the following route to handle the request.

```
app.get('/resetpassword.html/:resetcode', function (req, res) {
    console.log("reset code: " + req.params.resetcode);
    //res.render('resetpassword.html/' + req.params.resetcode);
    res.render('resetpassword.html', { resetcode: req.params.resetcode });
});
```

And my angular configurations as follows

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', { templateUrl: 'home.html' })
      .when('/resetpassword.html/:resetcode', { templateUrl: '/resetpassword.html', controller: 'ResetPasswordCtrl' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
    ;

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

I can access the path from $location so I can parse for the query string. But is that the only way I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is RouteParams

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am getting an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your route like this to be able to use `$routeParams`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/resetpassword.html/:resetcode', /**route**/);
```

Then you should be able to get the reset code using `$routeParams.resetcode`.

Comment: I already have the mentioned configuration but still not working.

Comment: Have yout tried it with multiple browsers? It works fine for me but only if `html5Mode` is turned off.